# Play 2.4 / Slick 3.1: database evolution connection leak

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-2.4, hikaricp

I have a default setup of Play 2.4 and Slick 3.1 and I'm using database evolutions (my db is PostgreSQL). It seems that evolutions create a connection leak.

I'm connecting to two databases (prod and test):

```
slick.dbs.default.driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/et"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "postgres"
slick.dbs.default.db.password = "postgres"

slick.dbs.test.driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
slick.dbs.test.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.test.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/et_test"
slick.dbs.test.db.user = "postgres"
slick.dbs.test.db.password = "postgres"
```

This is the connection count before the application is started:

```
et=# select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;
 count 
-------
     3
(1 row)
```

This is the connection count after the application is started:

```
et=# select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;
 count 
-------
    45
(1 row)
```

It would seem each database allocates 21 connections - 42 in total, fair enough.

This is the connection count after the "apply evolutions" is clicked:

```
et=# select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;
 count 
-------
    87
(1 row)
```

It seems evolutions allocate 21 more connections per database, so another 42.

After 10 minutes of application running idle:

```
et=# select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;
 count 
-------
    87
(1 row)
```

This looks like an obvious connection leak created by evolutions, doesn't it? Correct me if I'm wrong. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I guess,You are running play in dev mode. When you are doing change  in code or something else, play automatically  restart  application with new connection pool and that time Play did not shutdown existing pool.This problem i have faced.